# Drag file from local machine and Drop in app through protractor test

Tags: protractor

Drag file from local machine and Drop in app through protractor test
Is there any suggestion? My drag area looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onucz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be able to drag drop from outside the window..

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just an `input` field? If so, you should use `sendKeys` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean file upload (not drag and drop) try this function

```
import * as path from 'path';

function uploadFile(fullPath: string) {
    const sh = require('shelljs');
    const cwd = sh.pwd().toString();
    const absolutePath = path.join(cwd, fullPath);

    $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
}
```